# Dialetto con 'volede' per 'volete'?

Tags: regional

Questa domenica a Lisbona ho sentito parlare italiano. C'erano due coppie, e tutti parlavano in modo strano (per me), con /d/ dove m'aspettavo /t/ intervocalica. Questa è una caratteristica delle lingue romanze occidentali ma non dell'italiano. Sapete se c'è da qualche parte un dialetto con queste caratteristiche?

Comment: Né la domanda né la risposta sono doppioni, ma per tenere insieme le cose vicine, vedi anche: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5757/what-does-grazie-bui-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nell’Italia mediana (parte delle Marche, dell’Umbria e del Lazio) si ha un principio di sonorizzazione, che si combina a volte con la spirantizzazione e che ha per grado estremo una pronuncia chiaramente sonora (es. la *trota* ‹la dròda, la dħròdħa›). In genere si ha il passaggio dei suoni /-k-, -t-, -p- /, tra vocali, rispettivamente a /-g-, -d-, -v-/ (detto *sonorizzazione* o *lenizione*): [ˈdiga] «dica», [aˈvud] «avuto», [kaˈvei] «capelli»;

La sonorizzazione delle consonanti sorde precedute da nasale è tipica dei dialetti centro-meridionali e può superare i confini lessicali. Alcuni esempi: in umbro [ˈkambo], [ˈdɛnde], [ˈbjaɲgo] per *campo*, *dente*, *bianco*; in abruzz. [anˈdiːkɘ], [ˈvenʤɘ] per *antiche*, *vincere*; in barese [sɘnʤɘrɘˈta], [ˈlanʣɘ], [nonˈdɛɲgɘ] per *sincerità*, *lancia*, *non tengo*; e nel napol. [anˈʤinɘ], [nʣaˈlaːta], [ˈɲganːa], [noŋ ˈgwando] per *uncino, insalata, in canna, non quanto*.

Comment: Sembra abbastanza come quello che ho sentito. Ma per quanto riguarda le consonanti precedute da nasale, curiosamente, quando siamo andati a Napoli, non ho notato nulla.